# Programming a cylinder in a flow using the VIC method

Tags: c++, fluid-dynamics

I am still new in the programming world.
I have a small school project where i have to program a flow pass a cylinder using the VIC (Vortex in Cell) method.
I already have the program for VIC method but i don't know how to apply it on a cylinder.
The program is written in C++ and I executed it on Visual Studio Express 2013. 
I have got results for 1 cell.

Comment: I need to apply the VIC method on a flow around a tube but i don't know how to connect the method with the physical body (Tube)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I rather suspect that most people here don't know enough about fluid dynamics to help you (I don't think I ever knew enough, and what I knew I've forgotten).  At the very least, you'd need to identify where your VIC method comes form, and you'd need to show the code that you've tried.